# Angular5 handles JSON as string?

Tags: json, angular5

I have a JSON which I get htough a observable:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this._dataService.adjacencySubject$.subscribe(data => {
    this.adjacencyData = data.adjacencyData;     
});
```

}

`this.adjacencyData` is
    {      "x1": {"x1": "0", "x2": "1", "x3": "0", "x4": "1", "x5": "1"},      "x2": {"x1": "1", "x2": "0", "x3": "0", "x4": "1", "x5": "0"},      "x3": {"x1": "0", "x2": "1", "x3": "0", "x4": "0", "x5": "1"},      "x4": {"x1": "1", "x2": "1", "x3": "1", "x4": "0", "x5": "0"},      "x5": {"x1": "1", "x2": "0", "x3": "1", "x4": "1", "x5": "0"}}

when I now do:

```
 for (let x in this.adjacencyData ) {
      console.log(x);
    }
```

I get all the indexes count `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ....`

when I do:

```
for (let x in this.adjacencyData) {
      console.log(this.adjacencyData[x]);
    }
```

.. I get

```
{
"
x
"
:
"
x
1
"
.....
```

What  did I misunderstood? I need to get ethe keys and also the values somehow through iterating.

Comment: what is `adjacencyData` here?

Comment: oh sorry.. `adjacencyData ` is the JSON that I want to parse

Comment: Can you please add that `adjacencyData` content also?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I updated the question

Comment: Now the jsonData is missing in your question. Also what is the output you are getting when you say `I get all the indexes count`, can you add that details also.

Comment: I have updated the details